# How to write REST web service in cakephp using Post ..?

Tags: json, cakephp, rest, post

i am trying to make a REST web service for login in cakephp, now i want to sent userid and password through http post method as a JSON in cakephp.
thanks

Comment: Google is your friend: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1238/REST

Comment: what do you want? Up the RESTful service or call from CakePHP to a RESTful service?

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question. Your bounty won't help you get an answer if the question isn't clear.

Comment: We need more details - especially since you barely ever accept an answer from anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can sent json through Http post in cakephp

```
    <?php
 $data = array('Users'=>array('id'=>'1','username'=>'xyz','password'=>'pass','email'=>'xyz@xya.com','age'=>'28','gender'=>'male')); 
$url = "http://localhost/appname/Controllername/functionname";


    $content = json_encode($data);

    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.$content);
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $json_response;?>
```

Comment: hi Abba Bryant i am expecting some thing like this if any thing better than this i will award bounty to them.

Comment: You should use HttpSocket instead of curl.